# BarChart LabelingFunction->Right label overlaps with chart label when BarOrigin -> Left

Tags: labeling, charts

```
data = <|"Location NH" -> 1, "Location MO" -> 1, "Location WA" -> 2, 
  "Location OH" -> 3, "Location CO" -> 4, "Location CA" -> 6, 
  "Location TX" -> 7, "Location IL" -> 150|>

BarChart[data, LabelingFunction -> Right, BarOrigin -> Left, 
 ChartLabels -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 600]
```

The label overlaps with the axis and chart label

[image]

Is there a way to get the label to appear to the left of the bar rather than inside the left side of the bar? Similar to `Above`, which displays the label above the top of the bar?

```
BarChart[data, LabelingFunction -> Above, ChartLabels -> Automatic, 
 ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For putting the labels the *right* of the bar you can use `LabelingFunction -> After`:

```
BarChart[data, LabelingFunction -> After, BarOrigin -> Left, 
 ChartLabels -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!. All of the possible values `Left`, `Right`, `Above`, `Below`, `Center`, `After`, `Before`, etc. don't seem to be documented in a single page.

Comment: @Rohit, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept. You are right about documentation.   The possible values for the second argument of `Placed` varies depending on where it is used.